# How to import multiple jpg files from a folder and convert to string (base64)?

Tags: python, loops, import, base64

I want to read/import all the image (jpg) files from a folder and convert these into Base64 one by one using some loop. I tried with the following code. But it doesn't show any result.

```
import os
import base64
directory = "path"
files = os.listdir(directory)
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        with open(os.path.join(file, 'rb')) as image_file:
        my_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
        print(my_string)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately this is not a code writing or tutorial site. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempt(s)

Comment: If you broke it down to smaller parts, i.e., how to get a list of all files in a folder, how to filter files by extension, how to read a file and how to convert a string/bytestream into base64, it'd become more manageable

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? First write something and come back when you get error message.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get all the jpeg in the directory

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("/mydir"):
    if file.endswith(".jpeg"):
        print(os.path.join("/mydir", file))
```

convert it to base64 using this

```
import base64
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

with open("image.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    data = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

you may want to change the code a little bit to get data of all the image, you can then append all the base64 data to a list. You can do this easily using for loop.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestion. Actually, I am new to this community. So, I unable to put my problem properly. I edited my question. Can you have a look at the code and let me know what I am missing?

Comment: @G. Anderson I tried with the code you provided but the following error message is shown:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: @Md.ShabbirHossainBhuiya you have to first install PIL with pip install pillow first and then try again

Answer (score 0):

As far as i observe ...listing files in a folder returns only the file name not the full path .. compute the path with os.path.join(directory, file). os.path.isfile returns false if the file doesn't exist.